# send Ctrl+Shift+6 over serial using C#

Tags: c#, serial-port, keyboard-shortcuts

I am trying to send CTRL+SHIFT+6 to a Cisco router using Serial in C#, i have seen many examples for sending CTRL + 6 but do not understand how to combine CTRL & SHIFT & 6 together. Could someone help me understand how to combine these chars so i can send the key sequence via serial.

Regards from Ed.

```
   SerialPort m_serialPort = new SerialPort(serialPort, 9600);
   m_serialPort.ReadTimeout = 3000;
   m_serialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
   m_serialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
   m_serialPort.DataBits = 8;
   m_serialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
   m_serialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(SerialPort_DataReceived);
   m_serialPort.Open();
   Thread.Sleep(1000);
   m_serialPort.Write("\r\n");
   m_serialPort.Write("^(6)"); // attempt at trying to send CTRL+SHIFT+6
```

Comment: please give us some context as to how you are connecting.

Comment: Sure if that is of help?

Comment: Try to send the binary value 0x1e, i.e. `m_serialPort.Write(new byte[] { 0x1e });`

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Codo, that was the correct byte value. I had to make a minor adjustment to the syntax to send the value as a byte via Serial as seen below.

```
 m_serialPort.Write(new byte[] { 0x1e }, 0, 1);
```